# How to add custom user role in the registration form process in magento 2?

Tags: custom, registration, user, role

I am new to magento platform. I am using magento version 2.4.2 for my project, I want to add the select user type field in registration form. When customer registers. Is it possible to add the custom user role while registration with having certain permissions to use admin dashboard. I a new to magento I dont know how and which files I need to edit for the code.
I have not found any resources for the registration form customization. Or do I need to create a separate registration form for custom user role. Like for example I want to add other user role and operator.
Please help me. I am new and at beginner level in magento.
I ahev tried to create customer group but I cant get to set the user role with it and permission admin dashoard permissions to the customer group.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to do the following things.

1. First create the different roles and assign permission to that role from the magento admin.
2. Now in front-end registration process, add the extra fields according to your requirement.
3. Create the magento observer or plugin according to requirement for the user registration process. When user register successfully from front-end, using those information create admin user programmatically.
4. Now the newly created admin user, assign the proper role programmatically.